# How to make beautifull url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, slug

I have url like `http://example.com/posts/?tag=2`

My `routes.rb` is

```
resources :posts do
  get 'tag', :on => :collection
end
```

I need link like `http://example.com/posts/tag/linux`

My tables are:

```
posts(id,title)
tags(id,name)
taggings(id, post_id, tag_id)
```

Comment: Several options here: https://gist.github.com/1209732

Answer (score 2):

You could do sth. like

```
resources :posts do
  get 'tag/:name', on: :collection
end
```

In you controller you can find the tag with the name in your url params and get all posts with this tag.

```
Tag.where(name: params[:name]).posts
```

Or you implement a function in your `Post` model like `find_by_tag(tag)` that does that for you so you just have to call

```
Post.find_by_tag(params[:name])
```

in your controlllers action what is better readable.